# Football/Soccer Database Design

Tags: database-design

I'm a beginner with a bit of programming experience. I'm trying to make a little football/soccer database to learn how to structure databases better. Can someone tell me if this is a good design.

I have the following tables to structure the leagues:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_competitions
(
    id INT,
    predecessor INT,
    successor INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_competition_names
(
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR,
    competition_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );

CREATE TABLE tbl_competition_seasons
(
    id INT,
    competition_id INT,
    season VARCHAR,
    name VARCHAR,
    previous INT,
    next INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The competitions table will be for different competitions (e.g. English Premier League) which is also known by different names (e.g. EPL, Premier League) which are stored in the competition_names table. For now I'm think of using predecessor/successor for cases where the league was disbanded, renewed, etc.

Then we have the competition_seasons table for the different seasons (e.g. 2019-20, 2020-21, etc). It will hold the full name of the season (e.g. 2020-21 Premier League). previous and next point to the previous and next seasons.

What do you think so far?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing while designing database is to find entities and relationships between them. Once we find that we can try to reduce redundancy in the column examples the process is called `normalization`

Here I believe we have two entities. `league` and `season`. You do not need extra table for league name.

I would suggest database design as follows.

```
TABLE tbl_league
(
    id INT (primary key)
    name VARCHAR
);

TABLE tbl_competition(
    id INT (primary key)
    competition_id INT (foreign key => tbl_league)
    competition_time TIME
    season_time VARCHAR
    venue VARCHAR
    status VARCHAR Enum( PLAYED, DISABANED, RENEWED )
);
```

The information of predecessor or successor can be found by SQL queries. For eg.

```
select * from tbl_competition where competition_time > '2018-01-01' limit 1;
```